# Sort an array of CGPoints based on external point

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of CGPoints and would like to sort it based on the closest distance to an external point. I have done the following but it returns incorrect results.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.availableRenderPoints sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSValue *obj1, NSValue *obj2)
{
    CGPoint p1 = [obj1 CGPointValue];
    CGPoint p2 = [obj2 CGPointValue];

    CGFloat distance1 = ccpDistance(startPoint, p1);
    CGFloat distance2 = ccpDistance(startPoint, p2);

    if (distance1 <= distance2) return p1.y < p2.y;
    if (distance2 <= distance1) return p2.y < p1.y;

    return p1.x < p2.x;
}];
```

How can this be sorted based on closest distance to startPoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't it be just

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.availableRenderPoints sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSValue *obj1, NSValue *obj2)
{
    CGPoint p1 = [obj1 CGPointValue];
    CGPoint p2 = [obj2 CGPointValue];

    CGFloat distance1 = ccpDistance(startPoint, p1);
    CGFloat distance2 = ccpDistance(startPoint, p2);

    if (distance1 < distance2) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if (distance2 < distance1) return NSOrderedDescending;

    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

?

Comment: Should probably just be `<` (not `<=`)

Answer (score 0):

Martin R's answer looks good to me, but using `ccpDistance` means taking a square root, which is unnecessary.  You may get better performance by comparing the squared distances:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.availableRenderPoints sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSValue *obj1, NSValue *obj2) {
    CGPoint p1 = [obj1 CGPointValue];
    CGPoint p2 = [obj2 CGPointValue];

    CGFloat squaredDistance1 = ccpLengthSQ(ccpSub(p1, startPoint));
    CGFloat squaredDistance2 = ccpLengthSQ(ccpSub(p2, startPoint));

    // Sort by nearness to startPoint.
    // If equally near, sort by Y coordinate.
    // If equal Y coordinate, sort by X coordinate.
    return
        distance1 < distance2 ? NSOrderedAscending
        : distance2 > distance1 ? NSOrderedDescending
        : p1.y < p2.y ? NSOrderedAscending
        : p2.y < p1.y ? NSOrderedDescending
        : p1.x < p2.x ? NSOrderedAscending
        : p2.x < p1.x ? NSOrderedDescending
        : NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

On the other hand, if your array is small or the square root is fast enough, avoiding the square root may not make a noticeable difference.